# Alternate way to make command?

Tags: makefile, compilation

> I want to use *my_name* to compile my program ; instead of **make**
>   command . Any idea to do the same ??

Comment: Make is generally used to compile the program, not run it. Once it is compiled, you should be able to run it using the executable. Also, what language is this for?

Comment: What is "the program"? Do you want to execute Make or your program?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is difficult to decipher, but one approach is to make a shell script that calls `make` (or your program, if that's what you're asking about) and name this script whatever you want.